# Which of the following is(are) false?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, uniform-continuity

For $ E \subset \mathbb{R}$, consider the following statements:

$P$: Every continuous function $f: E \to \mathbb{R}$ is uniformly continuous.

$Q$: $E$ is compact.

$R$: Every continuous function $f: E \to \mathbb{R}$ is bounded.

Which of the following is(are) false?

(A) $ R \nRightarrow  P$

(B) $ P \implies Q$

(C) $ Q \implies P$

(D) $ R \implies Q$

> Solution:

$ R \Rightarrow Q$ is correct statement, it's a theorem. Similarly, $Q \Rightarrow P $ is also correct. 
That means, options (C),(D) are correct.

Please help me in verifying options (A) and (B), how should I approach these two options? In general, how to get a counter-example for such questions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$R$ does imply $P$ because $R$ implies $Q$ and $Q$ implies $P$.

(B) is false: consider $\mathbb N$ with the usual metric. Any real function on this space is uniformly continuous but this space is not compact.

Comment: I think "$Q$ implies $R$" should be "$Q$ implies $P$".

Comment: @RobertFurber Thanks. That was  a typo.